# C# .Net reading a string input from a form post

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm kind of newbie in C#.net . Im doing a form post on Client side which post a csv to my Controller

in My controller I'm unable to read the value. My goal is to finally create a csv file hence I'm avoiding the ajax post. I have the action on my form directing to the correct Url and Im appending the input to the form.

I have something like this on my client side

```
    WatchList_Class.prototype.Downloads1 = function(csv) {
 var input = '<input type= "text" id="uploadCsv" name="uploadCsv" value=""' +        csv + ' />';
     $('form#uploadCSV').append(input);
     $('form#uploadCSV').submit();
    };
```

On the controller side I have

```
   public ActionResult ExportCSVFile(string data) //Im getting data as null
{
  string toReturn = Server.UrlDecode(data);
  return File(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toReturn), "text/csv", "exportedData.csv");

}
```

Im getting string data as null;

Can Any one point out what Im doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, the non-nullness of `data` will be entirely predicated on your having a form element with a name of `data` somewhere on the client.  Nothing in the code you provided indicates one way or another that you have such an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportCSVFile(HttpPostedFileBase uploadCsv)
{
    uploadCsv.SaveAs("exportedData.csv");
}
```

(Also note that in your code, the name of your paramater `data` did NOT match the name of your input control `uploadCsv`)

Comment: I have a quick question on the same line what would be the Controller code will be like for reading a string from a form post say the string contain a password. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's a password, it's still a string on the server side. So just use `... MyAction(string password) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter has to match the name of the POST variable. So instead of data use uploadCsv:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportCSVFile(string uploadCsv) 
{
  string toReturn = Server.UrlDecode(data);
  return File(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toReturn), "text/csv", "exportedData.csv");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the encoding type on the upload form?

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely reason is your ID for data does not match name of the argument in your ExportCSVFile handler. Use Fiddler to check what is actually posted to your page.